# Position polar coordinate pcolormesh at exact coordinate position in plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I want to place the center of a polar coordinate plot at a coordinate in a cartesian plot.

My toy code looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
X_test_i = np.zeros((5, 2))
X_test_i[0] = [10 ,10]
X_test_i[1] = [20 ,20]
X_test_i[2] = [30 ,30]
X_test_i[3] = [40 ,40]
X_test_i[4] = [50 ,50]

model_prediction_i = np.random.random((200,360))

ax.plot(X_test_i[:, 0], X_test_i[:, 1], 'b', label='Observation', linewidth=1, antialiased=True)
ax.plot(X_test_i[:, 0][-1], X_test_i[:, 1][-1], marker='o', markersize=7, color="red",
                        label='Current position', antialiased=True)


t = np.radians(np.linspace(0, 360, np.shape(model_prediction_i)[0]))
r = np.arange(0, np.shape(model_prediction_i)[1], 1)
R, T = np.meshgrid(r, t)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
ax1.pcolormesh(T, R, model_prediction_i, cmap="Reds")


ax.set_xlim([0, 100])
ax.set_ylim([0, 200])

fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig(os.path.join("C:/Users/X/Documents", "test" + '{0}'.format(1) + ".pdf"),
            dpi=100, transparent=True)
plt.close(fig)
```

`X_test_i` marks the curve and the last point of it, marked with the red dot (hard to see, but coordinates are (50, 50)) should be the center of the `pcolormesh`. At the moment it looks like this:[image]

But I want to move the circular grid to be centered on the red dot. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Any specific reason, why you don't change the scaling to `ax.set_xlim([0, 2 * X_test_i[4][0]]), ax.set_ylim([0, 2 * X_test_i[4][1]])` to have `X_test_i[4]` in the center of the plot?

Comment: Normally the circular plot should visualize a probability distribution over the possible continuations of the blue line. So the coordinates of the blue line must stay the same.

Comment: I obviously don't understand the connection between the two plots. From what you say I understand that a) the circular plot has to be within the limits of [0, 100], [0, 200], b) its centre has to move to the position [50,50]. This is somewhat contradictory.

Comment: I don't care if the whole circular plot is visible or not, all I want is to move the center of the circular plot to the position (50, 50)

Comment: `ax.set_ylim(np.array([-dy, dy])+y0), ax.set_xlim(np.array([-dx, dx])+x0)` where you can set dx and dy to be what ever you want and x0 and y0 are where you want the view of the plot centred...

Comment: Example with regard to my code?